# "GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name 'export'" when loading graphql queries with webpack

Tags: webpack, graphql, apollo

I followed [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/integrations/webpack/#fragments) documentation from apollo on how to load queries with webpack, adding this rule to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
        {
          test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
        },
```

but when I run my ejected (five years ago) CRA app, I get this error:

```
"GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name 'export'"
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of debugging in node modules, I found that the new `.graphql` files were falling through to the final loader of the webpack rules, the file-loader. Hence why they were being prepended with an `export` keyword (which resolved as an invalid token keyword in `graphql-tag`):

```
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
```

to fix this, make sure to also exclude `.graphql` and  `.gql` for this loader:

```
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|gql|graphql)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
```